# Does unsubscribing the observable or subject destroys it?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a scenario in my application where I am listening to key expiry events in Redis.
I have created a subject and whenever there is an expiration event in redis, I push the expired key name in the `expirationEventPool$` subject like this:

```
private async keepListeningForKeyExpiryEvents(): Promise<void> {
    await this.redisEventListenerConnection.redis.pSubscribe("__keyevent@0__:expired", (message: string) => {
        this.expirationEventPool$.next(message);
    });
}
```

This happens right after the application bootstraps, now sometime later in the application lifecycle, if some method sets the expiry of the key *(say after 10 seconds)* and asks for the expiry observer, I return the observable from `expirationEventPool$` like this:

```
public listenForEntityExpiration(entityName: string, entityId: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.expirationEventPool$.pipe(
        first((expiredEntityKey: string) => {
            return expiredEntityKey === `${entityName}:${entityId}`;
        }),
    );
}
```

Now, the method who has asked for the entity expiration event, subscribes to it. After the `expirationEventPool$` has emitted a value, it will get automatically unsubscribe because of the `first` operator. My question is, can I resubscribe to the same `expirationEventPool$` subject again? Or does it gets destroyed after the unsubscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `expirationEventPool$` is a hot observable, yes you can resubscribe to it.